# NoSQLUnit MongoDB insert collection names are []

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to write a JUnit test case for a Spring MongoDB Repository class in a Spring Boot project. But I keep getting the exception.

> com.lordofthejars.nosqlunit.core.NoSqlAssertionError: Expected
>   collection names are [student] but insert collection names are []

Any suggestions? Many thanks!

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ComponentScan("com.tp.repository")
public class TestConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() {
        return new Fongo("Fongo").getMongo();
    }

    @Bean
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "test";
    }

}
```

Unit Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class StudentRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Rule
    public MongoDbRule mongoDbRule = MongoDbRuleBuilder.newMongoDbRule()
            .defaultSpringMongoDb("student");

    @Test
    @ShouldMatchDataSet(location = "/student.json")
    public void shouldSave() {
        studentRepository.save(createStudent());
    }

    private Student createStudent() {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setFirstName("First");
        student.setLastName("Last");
        return student;
    }

}
```

Student class

```
@Document(collection="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed
    private String firstName;

    @Indexed
    private String lastName;

    ....
}
```

Comment: What `Student` class looks like?

Comment: Thanks, Szymon. A snippet of Student class has been added to the question.

Comment: The problem seems to be with @ShouldMatchDataSet. If I remove that annotation, `Assert.assertEquals(1, studentRepository.count());` would execute with no exception. Could it be a compatibility issue between NoSQLUnit 0.8.1 and Spring 4?

Answer (score 0):

yes in theory it should work, but for some reason I don't know why it is not working. It is true that my examples and tests uses xml approach instead of configuration approach, but it should work in both cases.  It seems like there would be two Fongo instances where one is used to insert data and another one to check data. Can you provide the code in a github account so I can debug and see what's happening?